# GCE Persistent SSD disks allocate more IOPS than specified

Tags: performance, google-cloud-platform, ssd, google-compute-engine, iops

I've been testing GCE and created a VM with a persistent SSD disk to test disk performance. Persistent SSD disk that I configured was 37GB, which was supposed to give me 1110 IOPS but when I run diskspd.exe with the following parmeters, I get 1500 IOPS.

```
-d300 -c34G -w100 -b8K -F4 -r -o64 -h -L D:\test.dat -P
```

I have done the exact same test with exact same parameters on Azure & AWS but I always got what I configured. Does anybody know why GCE is acting the way it does? Having more IOPS then what I pay for is good, but I'd like to know if the opposite isn't going to happen.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the explanation is that the output you receive when creating a new persistent SSD disk is an estimation, that being said this value can change. Perhaps it's a guarantee that for a 37 GB persistent SSD disk it will give you 1110 IOPS, but performance can increase.